# Is uninstall/reinstall the best way to update PyCharm on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, installation, pycharm, updates, reinstall

When I open PyCharm I get a nag that I need to update.  So I followed the link and found that it lead to a download of a new version.  Fine.  I downloaded it and started the installation wizard expecting to find an "Update" option.  But it goes right to asking me if I want to uninstall my old version.  I hesitate because I don't want to hose what is a good working system.

Looking for the voice of experience ... Are there any gotchas connected with uninstall/reinstall for PyCharm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably unnecessary by now, but in case anyone sees this in the future, what this does is uninstalls the previous version of PyCharm (or any Jetbrains IDE for that matter), but keeps for config and settings files intact. Once you uninstall the last version and install the newer one, you'll be able to import your settings from past versions.

**EDIT**: 
Shortly after this, I discovered Jetbrains [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/) which basically lets you update your IDEs dynamically, without having to uninstall/install manually.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I was not able to import my previous settings, and some of my old projects were not able to load. I will definitely not be tricked into "updating" this software again, no matter how much they nag me.

Comment: You must've uninstalled the config files for the IDE. Check out the updated answer for alternatives!

Comment: I also couldn't import old settings. I'm pretty sure i opted to NOT delete them when asked.